# Hibernate: how to update element order in a list (order generated by @orderColumn) without fetching the list

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I have entity with list of sub entities, and I want to keep the order of the sub entities so I used the annotation  @OrderColumn.

```
@OrderColumn(name = "pos")
private List<Child> children;
```

now I wish to change position of one child in the list, the way to do that is to fetch the list of child and then change the order in the list, then flush/commit this change.

but I want to do it in the DB with **hql/hibernate criteria** update statement. (because children list may be a huge list and I don't want to spend time on fetching this)

how can I access my generated field (`pos`) in hql/hibernate criteria?
is there a way yo do it?

Comment: Do you want your result to be sorted before fetching ? Pleas clarify.

Comment: @JayeshChoudhary I don't care at this point, I just want to update the order, and then in the future, upon fetching,  they will sorted by the new order, in my current transaction i don't need them to be ordered just to update the order